# Calculating PACF of $ARMA(p,q)$

Tags: statistics, time-series

I am struggling with the calculation of PACF (partial autocorrelated functions) in $ARMA(p,q)$. The lecture notes I have gives an example of calculating PACF of $AR(1)$. For $$y_t=a_0+a_1y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,$$ what the note does is to redefine $$y_t^*=y_t-E(y_t)$$ and obtain $y_t^*=\phi_{11}y_{t-1}^*+e_t$ where $\phi_{11}$ is the first PACF value. Then it uses Yule-Walker equations to find PACF. However, I am not too sure the general way to do it. For example, if for $AR(2)$, do we have $y_t^*=\phi_{11}y_{t-1}^*+e_t$ or $y_t^*=\phi_{11}y_{t-1}^*+\phi_{12}y_{t-2}^*+e_t$? In fact, I was even not sure what that $e_t$ should eqaul...

I am hoping that someone could tell me the general way for calculating this, or provide some simple but more general examples, say $AR(2)$, to elucidate the progress of the calculation. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may be less about theory than about practice, but can give you the clue.

> The partial autocorrelations may be estimated by fitting succsessively autoregressive models of orders $1, 2, 3, ...$ by least squares ... and picking out the estimates ... of the last coefficient fitted at each stage.

[Time Series Analysis: Forecasting and Control](http://books.google.by/books?id=jyrCqMBW_owC&lpg=PA69&ots=LPK3dfFON5&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false) (chapter 3.2.6, page 69)